Find the value of $L$, limit $n$ tends to infinity

Suppose the limit $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\right)$$

exists and is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$, find $L$.

In the original question, we just have to find the upper bound which is very easy as we know that $(1+x^2)^n>(1+nx^2)$, but I am curious to find the exact limit.

Let's denote $$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
Applying integration by parts, we get $$I_n=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}{\biggl|}_0^1+2n\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}dx$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+2n\int_0^1\frac{x^2+1-1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}dx$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+2n\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{n}}-2n\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+2n I_n-2n I_{n+1}$$
Hence we can say that, $$\boxed{I_n=\frac{2n}{2n-1}I_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2^n(2n-1)}}$$
Now after this, the real game starts.
We have to find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}I_n$
We have, $$\sqrt{n}I_n=\frac{2n\sqrt{n}}{2n-1}I_{n+1}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2^n(2n-1)}$$
Now, when $n$ tends to $\infty$ we will have $I_n=I_{n+1}=0$
I am not able to continue after this. How to handle this $0×\infty$ form$?$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

you missed a term, $2^{-n}$ also has to be divided by $2n-1$

@gt6989b I'm correcting it just now

Here is the solution from Wolfram Alpha

@gt6989b what was that!!! ...i get chills whenever I see hypergeometric function

Attempt at asymptotics

Use the substitution $\sqrt{n}x=y$:
$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{dy}{\left(1+\frac{y^2}{n}\right)^n}\longrightarrow \int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}$$
by dominated convergence.

Hey...can you pls elaborate... I've never heard of this theorem

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad use any convergence theorem you want. Dominated convergence is simplistic because you only need to find a dominating function (in this case, $\frac{1}{1+y^2}\geq f_n(y)$ for each $n$, suffices) the existence of which is the only precondition for allowing the interchange of the limit and the integral. But you can use any theorem you want. I just like to scream from the rooftops to remember that $u$-substitution exists, which every student of higher mathematics always ignores in these problems. It is a very simple technique many people forget exists.

Use that following theorem：Useful result


Suppose $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, with $f(0)=1$ and $|f(x)|<1$ on $(0,b]$.
Let $c,p>0$. If $f(x)=1-cx^p +o(x^p)$ as $x\to0$, then
$$\int_0^b f(x)^n\ dx\sim\frac{\Gamma(1/p)}{pc^{1/p}}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}$$
as $n\to\infty.$


Let $x=\tan t$, then
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos^{2n-2}x\ dx
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\cos^2x)^{n-1}\ dx.$$
Let $f(x)=\cos^2x=1-x^2+o(x^2),x\to0$,
by the theorem above, here $c=1,p=2$
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}(\cos^2x)^{n-1}\ dx\sim
\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt n}=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2\sqrt n}.$$
So
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\right)
=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}.$$

You inspired me and I thank you for that as well as for your nice answer. Cheers :-)

We begin by observing that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x,
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x
& < \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + x \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{x}^{n}} \text {d} x \\
& = \int_{0}^{1 / 2} {x}^{n} \cdot \frac {1}{{x}^{2}} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{\left( n - 1 \right) {2}^{n - 1}},
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt {n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt {n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x.
$$
Recognise that the new integral is a beta integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + x \right)}^{n}} \cdot \frac {1}{2} {x}^{1 / 2 - 1} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{2} \, \text {B} \left( \frac {1}{2}, \, n - \frac {1}{2} \right).
$$
We know
$$
\text {B} \left( \frac {1}{2}, \, n - \frac {1}{2} \right)
= \frac {\Gamma \left( 1 / 2 \right) \Gamma \left( n - 1 / 2 \right)}{\Gamma \left( n \right)},
$$
where
$$
\Gamma \left( n - \frac {1}{2} \right) = \frac {\left( 2 n - 3 \right)!!}{{2}^{n - 1}} \, \Gamma \left( \frac {1}{2} \right)
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\left( 2 n - 3 \right)!!
& = \frac {\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!}{\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!!} \\
& = \frac {\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!}{{2}^{n - 1} \left( n - 1 \right)!} \\
& = \frac {\left( n - 1 \right)!}{{2}^{n - 1}} \binom {2 n - 2}{n - 1}.
\end{align}
$$
Using this result, together with the fact that $\Gamma \left( 1 / 2 \right) = \sqrt {\pi}$, we derive
$$
\text {B} \left( \frac {1}{2}, \, n - \frac {1}{2} \right) = \frac {\pi}{{4}^{n - 1}} \binom {2 n - 2}{n - 1}.
$$
By Stirling's approximation,
$$
\binom {2 n}{n} = \frac {\left( 2 n \right)!}{{\left( n! \right)}^{2}} \sim \frac {\sqrt {2 \pi \cdot 2 n} \, {\left( 2 n / e \right)}^{2 n}}{\left( 2 \pi \cdot n \right) {\left( n / e \right)}^{2 n}} = \frac {{4}^{n}}{\sqrt {\pi n}}.
$$
Accordingly,
$$
\text {B} \left( \frac {1}{2}, \, n - \frac {1}{2} \right) \sim \sqrt {\frac {\pi}{n - 1}}.
$$
Plug this back. Finally, we conclude
$$
\boxed {\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt {n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + {x}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x
= \frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2}.}
$$

Let$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\tag{1}$$
And $$\mathcal I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}+\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=I_n+J_n\tag{2}$$
where
$$J_n=\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\leq\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{2n}}\to0,\text{ as }n\to\infty\tag{3}$$
Now, integration by parts:
$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal I_n&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\\&=\left.\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}\right|_{x=0}^\infty+2n\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=2n\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}-2n\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\\\mathcal I_n&=2n\mathcal I_n-2n\mathcal I_{n+1}\implies\color{red}{\mathcal I_{n+1}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\mathcal I_n=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\mathcal I_1=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac\pi2}
\end{aligned}$$
By Stirling's approximation: $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$,
$$\mathcal I_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4^n}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac\pi2\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cdot\frac\pi2=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt n}$$
So, as $n\to\infty$, $I_n\sim\mathcal I_n$ or $I_n\sim\mathcal I_{n+1}$. The required limit is given by:
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt n\mathcal I_{n+1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}}}$$
I hope this helps!

More than inspired by @Riemann's solution.
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\cos^{2n-2}(t)\,dt$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n)}-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(n-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \right)$$
The beta term is negligible compared to the other one (for $n=100$, they are in a ratio of $\sim 10^{31}$). So, we have the upper bound.
Using Stirling approximation
$$I_n\sim  \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{n}} \left(1+\frac{3}{8 n}+\frac{25}{128 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$ which is a very good approximation (the relative error is less than $1.0$% if $n>5$ and less than $0.1$% if $n>8$).
This looks much simpler than trying to find the asymptotics of the Gaussian
$$I_n=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n;\frac{3}{2};-1\right)$$
